# Cant access XAMPP applications after installing IIS

Tags: iis, apache-2.2

I seem to have screwed my server installations. I installed IIS last night on my local machine that was running XAMPP on Win7.

Now, if I try to connect to my application from my laptop on the localnetwork using http://192.168.2.6/AppName I am unable to do so. This was working perfectly before I did that installation.

I can access http://192.168.2.6/AppName through the local machine just fine.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably both servers are running at the same port.
You can check that using the xampp control panel.
At the control panel, at the right hand side, click "Port-check"
and see which application is using which port.
You can reconfigure the port used by Apache very easily.
Look at

```
<your installation path>\apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

Normally apache uses port 80

Find this line:

```
Listen 80
```

change it to:

```
Listen 85
```

Comment: Yes. I guess that was the problem. I uninstalled IIS since I did not want to get too adventurous and everything is fine. But I believe your answer was correct.